# Django - custom attributes for model fields

Tags: django, tabs

Is there a way in Django to add custom attributes to a model's fields (without resorting to subclassing fields)?

I would like to only display certain fields in certain sections of my template.  This is because eventually each type of field will be displayed in a separate tab.  I thought about adding a custom attribute to each field to identify which section/tab it should go in.  But, so far, I've had no luck.

I have a few field types:

```
class Enum(set):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self:
            return name
        raise AttributeError

FieldTypes = Enum(["one","two","three",])
```

And a few models:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
  a = models.CharField()
  b = models.ForeignKey('Model2')
  c = models.IntegerField()
  a.type = FieldTypes.one  # this obviously doesn't work
  b.type = FieldTypes.two  # this obviously doesn't work
  c.type = FieldTypes.three  # this obviously doesn't work

class Model2(models.Model):
  d = models.CharField()
```

And a form:

```
class Form1(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Mode1
```

And a template:

```
{% for fieldType in FieldTypes %}
  <div class="{{fieldType}}">
      {% for field in form %}
        {% if field.type = fieldType %}
          {{ field }}
         {% endif %}
      {% endfor %} 
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

But this doesn't work.

Ideas?  Or other suggestions for only placing certain fields in certain sections of the page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I would keep this logic outside of the model class. Models shouldn't be tangled up with presentation elements if you can help it, and choosing which fields to display in a form seems like a presentation concern. Fortunately, the Form class provides a nice, UI-focused layer between the data layer (the model) and the presentation layer (the view and template).

Here's how I've addressed this in the past. In my Form class, I created a list of field groups, each with a title and a list of the names of the fields they contain:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field_groups = (
        {'name':'Group One', 'fields':('a', 'b', 'c')},
        {'name':'Group Two', 'fields':('d', 'e')},
    )
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

Then in the template, I looped through the groups, and within that loop conditionally included those fields:

```
{% for group in form.field_groups %}
<h3 class="groupheader">{{group.name}}</h3>
    {% for field in form %}
        {% if field.name in group.fields %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This allows you to control the grouping and display of form fields within the `MyModelForm` class, which is a reasonable place for presentation logic to live.

Answer (score 2):

It's posible!

```
class Model1(models.Model):
   a = models.CharField()
   b = models.ForeignKey('Model2')
   c = models.IntegerField()
```

And a form:

```
class Form1(forms.ModelForm):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Form1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['a'].type = FieldTypes.one
    self.fields['b'].type = FieldTypes.two
    self.fields['c'].type = FieldTypes.three


  class Meta:
    model = Mode1
```

Comment: This works in Django 3.1.5. While looping over fields in the template, a field's attribute (e.g. "type") can be accessed by "field.field.type".

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, that I do want this logic in my model class; the field types are used for more than just working out where/how to display them (though they are used for that too).  I have come up with the following solution.

I defined some classes to store a set of field types:

```
class FieldType(object):
    def __init__(self, type=None, name=None):
        self._type = type
        self._name = name

    def getType(self):
        return self._type

    def getName(self):
        return self._name

class FieldTypeList(deque):
    def __getattr__(self,type):
        for ft in self:
            if ft.getType() == type:
                return ft
        raise AttributeError

FieldTypes = FieldTypeList([FieldType("ONE","The Name Of Field One"),FieldType("TWO","The Name Of Field Two")])
```

And a few models each of which has a set of mappings from field types to particular field names (In this example, fields 'a', 'b', and 'c' are of type 'ONE' and field 'd' is of type 'TWO'):

```
class ParentModel(models.Model):
  _fieldsByType = {}

  a = models.CharField()
  b = models.CharField()

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(ParentModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      for ft in FieldTypes:
        self.setFieldsOfType(ft, [])
      self.setFieldsOfType(FieldTypes.ONE, ['a','b'])

  def setFieldsOfType(self,type,fields):
    typeKey = type.getType()
    if typeKey in self._fieldsByType:
      self._fieldsByType[typeKey] += fields
    else:
      self._fieldsByType[typeKey] = fields

class ChildModel(ParentModel):
  _fieldsByType = {}   # not really sure why I have to repeat this attribute in the derived class

  c = models.CharField()
  d = models.CharField()

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ChildModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.setFieldsOfType(FieldTypes. ['c'])
    self.setFieldsOfType(FieldTypes. ['d'])
```

I have a basic form:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = ChildModel
```

And a custom filter to return all fields of a given type from a particular form (note, the accessing the model from the form via its Meta class):

```
@register.filter
def getFieldsOfType(form,type):
    return form.Meta.model._fieldsByType[type.getType()]
```

And, finally, a template to pull it all together (the template takes MyForm and FieldTypes):

```
  {% for type in types %}
    <div id="{{type.getType}}">
      {% with fieldsOfType=form|getFieldsOfType:type %}
        {% for field in form %}
          {% if field.name in fieldsOfType %}
            <p>
              {{ field.errors }}
              {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
            </p>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endwith %}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
```