# How to set a custom attribute to a model which can be used in the template with ModelForm in Django?

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to write some attributes to a model field which can be used later to differentiate the different fields in the template?

model.py

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField("i am the Label", max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField("i am other Label", max_length=30, customattr="Custom")
```

forms.py

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        Person
```

template.html

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
     {% for field in form %}
         {% ifequal field.customattr 'Custom' %} # HOW COULD THIS WORK?
            <p>Hello world.</p>
            {{ field }}
         {% else %}
            <p>This is not Custom</p>
            {{ field }}
         {% endifequal %}
     {% endfor %}
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

Any hints?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407837/django-custom-attributes-for-model-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really possible; `field` in your template code is a form field, not a model field. I would shift the presentation logic from the model into the template, and do something like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
     {% for field in form %}
         {% if field.name == 'last_name' or field.name == 'another_field' %}
            <p>Hello world.</p>
            {{ field }}
         {% else %}
            <p>This is not Custom</p>
            {{ field }}
         {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

(the [== operator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#operator) was added in Django 1.2)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why yo would like to do this. If you would like to define custom html to your ModelForm field you can override it like this:

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        Person
    first_name = forms.CharField(
        required = True,
        widget   = forms.TextInput(attrs={'style':'width:100px;'},
    )
```

Like this you can tell Django how you would like to render your html.
You can find more detail in the doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets

Comment: hi @mounir i like to group fields with the help of an additional attribute. THe grouping i'm planning to do with field iterations...